Weyl transformation of induced metric
Consider the Weyl/conformal transformation in four dimenions
$$\tilde{g} \enspace = \enspace \Omega^2 g \quad \Longrightarrow \quad  \sqrt{-|\tilde{g}|} \enspace = \enspace \Omega^4 \sqrt{-|g|}$$
The divergence theorem reads
$$\int_M \! d^4x \, \sqrt{-|g|} \, \nabla_{\mu} X^{\mu} \enspace = \enspace \oint_{\partial M} \! d^3x \, \sqrt{-|h|} \, n_{\mu} X^{\mu} \tag{2}$$
for some vector $X$ and where $h$ is the induced metric of $g$ on the boundary.
QUESTION 1: Since $h$ is the induced metric of $g$ on the boundary (which is three dimensional), does it transform as
$$\sqrt{-|\tilde{h}|} = \Omega^4 \sqrt{-|h|} \qquad \text{or as} \qquad \sqrt{-|\tilde{h}|} = \Omega^3 \sqrt{-|h|} \tag{3}$$
My guess is, that it transforms with a factor $\Omega^3$, because the surface it describes is three dimensional. However, the induced matrix $h_{\mu \nu}$ of $g_{\mu \nu}$ on the boundary would remain $(4 \times 4)$, only that e.g. some coordinate in its entries is constant, and so the factor $\Omega^4$ would somehow be sensibel. What is the correct tranformation rule?
QUESTION 2:
Under the above Weyl transformation, the unit normal covector to the boundary transforms as
$$\tilde{n}_{\mu} \enspace = \enspace \Omega^{-1} n_{\mu}$$
Is this true for all covectors? If so, then the Weyltransformations would not only preserve angles, but also lengths, wouldn't they? So how come the normal covector transforms differently than other vectors? Does the partial derivative also transform as
$$\tilde{\partial}_{\mu} \enspace = \enspace \Omega^{-1} \partial_{\mu}$$
?

The definition of the induced metric is
$h(X,Y) := g(X,Y)$ if $X,Y$ are in tangent to $\partial M$.
Therefore $$\tilde{h} = \Omega^2 h\:.$$
Then we can see $h_{ab}$ and $\tilde{h}_{ab}= \Omega^2 h_{ab}$  as a function of the coordinates on $\partial M$ and, in this case it is a $3\times 3$ matrix. Consequently
$$\det \tilde{h} = \det [\tilde{h}_{ab}] = \det [\Omega^2 h_{ab}] = \Omega^6 \det h\:.$$
This answers your first question choosing your second guess.
Regarding unit normal co-vectors you have just to impose that the length with respect to the $\tilde{g}$ metric of $\tilde{n}_\mu$ is one exactly as it happens for $n$ with respect to $g$. Notice that transforming the metric with a factor $\Omega^2$ does not touch orthogonality, so the new ortonormal vector $\tilde{n}$ is parallel to the initial  one $n$, but its norm is different because the metric has changed:
$$1= \tilde{g}(\tilde{n}, \tilde{n}) = \Omega^2 g(\tilde{n}, \tilde{n}) =  g(\Omega\tilde{n}, \Omega\tilde{n}) $$
so that
$$\Omega\tilde{n}_\mu = n_\mu\:.$$
This is not true for all covectors. Tranforming the metric as said  does not automatically imply an action on vectors o co-vectors.
The above relation  between $n$ and $\tilde{n}$ just arises because you want that $n$ and $\tilde{n}$ are both normal to a same given co-dimension $1$ submanifold and that  the length of both them is $1$.
In particular,  operators $\partial_\mu$ remain fixed under rescaling of the metric.

Sorry for the follow-up, but I've stumbled upon something and want to make sure if I understood your answer correctly. Suppose $\partial M$ is a null hypersurface (HS). According to Eric Poisson's "A relativistic toolkit", Sec. 3.1 / p. 62 (see here), the induced metric of a null HS is a 2-tensor contrary to the induced metric of spacelike or timelike HS that are a 3-tensor. Does this imply that
$$\operatorname{det}(\bar{h}) = \Omega^4 \operatorname{det}(h)$$
or am I misunderstanding the terms 2-tensor and 3-tensor?

I do not know Poisson's definition. The induced metric on a n-dim submanifold, by definition, is the scalar product of vectors in the overall space which are also tangent to the submanifold. Hence it is a double covariant symmetric tensor on a n-dim manifold. It does not matter the nature of the submanifold. However, if it is a null manifold, the induced metric turns out to be degenerate.
